# Get part of string with PHP

Tags: php, string

i have this string:

```
$tree = 'list[0001Red]=null&list[0002Blue]=null&list[0004Sky]=0002Blue&list[0003Green]=null&list[0005Grass]=0003Green';
```

And I need to get just the first 4 characters that are before the opening bracket, for example.

```
$tree = '0001,0002,0004,0003,0005';
```

The four characters are generated randomly so they change.

Thanks for your help

I did it using this code

```
$tree = explode("list[", $tree);
$pieces = count($tree);
for($x=1; $x < $pieces; $x++){
    $temp = substr($tree[$x], 0, 4);
    if($x==1){
        $new_tree = $temp;
    }else{
        $new_tree = $new_tree . "," . $temp;
    }
}
```

But the solution of Andreas look better and  simple

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: [so] is *not* a code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I suggest reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `explode` the string using the `[` character, then a little `substr()` magic should do it...

Comment: Would you like to share how this odd string got generated. Maybe it would be simpler to fix the creation instead of fiddle with the useless results

Comment: @RiggsFolly It looks like a URL query string for a form with array-style input fields like `<input name="list[0001Red]">`

Comment: `preg_match_all()` should be a pretty easy way to accomplish what you want. Use a regular expression that matches 4 digits with `[` as a lookbehind.

Comment: @Barmar That would have been my guess also. Still think it could be better created in the form even if it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex

```
$arr = preg_match_all("/\[(\d{4})/", $tree);

$tree = implode(",", $arr[1]);
echo $tree; //0001,0002,0004,0003,0005
```

Comment: Regex is a neat tool. If you're new to it you can play around on this [Site](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) it will help you in these kinds of situations. But on the other hand it is a bit more resource heavy so don't use it if you don't really need to. +1 for being the 1 min faster. :)